# Getting error in file download ionic 3 on android 10 sdk29

Tags: android, typescript, ionic-framework

I am getting following error on android 10 not on lower versions  if I am using:
downloadDir = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 'download/';

```
const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
fileTransfer.download(sourceUrl, downloadDir + fileName, false).then((entry) => {
 })
```

> E/FileTransfer( 5726):
> {"code":1,"source":"https://example.azurewebsites.net/api/interactivelabel/export?ItemCode=1","target":"file:///storage/emulated/0/download/export-1.csv","http_status":200,"exception":"/storage/emulated/0/download/export-1.csv:
> open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"} 09-04 06:05:15.497
> E/FileTransfer( 5726): java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /storage/emulated/0/download/export-1.csv: open failed: EACCES
> (Permission denied) 09-04 06:05:15.497 E/FileTransfer( 5726):     at
> libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496) 09-04 06:05:15.497
> E/FileTransfer( 5726):    at
> java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:235) 09-04
> 06:05:15.497 E/FileTransfer( 5726):   at
> org.apache.cordova.CordovaResourceApi.openOutputStream(CordovaResourceApi.java:329)
> 09-04 06:05:15.497 E/FileTransfer( 5726):     at
> org.apache.cordova.CordovaResourceApi.openOutputStream(CordovaResourceApi.java:310)
> 09-04 06:05:15.497 E/FileTransfer( 5726):     at
> org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer$2.run(FileTransfer.java:811)
> 09-04 06:05:15.497 E/FileTransfer( 5726):     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> 09-04 06:05:15.497 E/FileTransfer( 5726):     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> 09-04 06:05:15.497 E/FileTransfer( 5726):     at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 09-04 06:05:15.497
> E/FileTransfer( 5726): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open
> failed: EACCES (Permission denied) 09-04 06:05:15.497 E/FileTransfer(
> 5726):    at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method) 09-04 06:05:15.497
> E/FileTransfer( 5726):    at
> libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167) 09-04 06:05:15.497
> E/FileTransfer( 5726):    at
> libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252) 09-04 06:05:15.497
> E/FileTransfer( 5726):    at
> libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167) 09-04 06:05:15.497
> E/FileTransfer( 5726):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7893)
> 09-04 06:05:15.497 E/FileTransfer( 5726):     at
> libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482) 09-04 06:05:15.497
> E/FileTransfer( 5726):    ... 7 more

Answer (score 0):

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Add that to the application tag in manifest file.